# I am deploying Rails6 app using Capistrano. Deploying fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to deploy my Rails 6 app to the server using Capistrano.

and I confronted this error message.

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`
```

Many other posts and article suggest some way with secret.yml file. but I wan not able to do it. Since I don't have a secret.yml file in the app as I am on Rails 6.

***UPDATE***.

I manually made file in folder.
config/secrets.yml

```
production:
  secret_key_base: ******************************
```

Still getting same errors.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. Or solution maybe. I did the following things.

### 1. Server Side.

in your server - `yourappfolder/shared/config/`
make `secrets.yml' file and write details.

```
deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx.:~/myapp/shared/config$ ls
secrets.yml
```

**secrets.yml**

```
production:
  secret_key_base: something---key------
```

### 2. Local machine

in your - `config/envirenments/production.rb` update this.

```
config.require_master_key = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `config/secrets.yml` and write the desired values.

Or

Set secret_key_base in application.rb

```rb
config.secret_key_base = 'blipblapblup'
```

Comment: It seems wrong. as I am on Rails 6. 'secrets.yml' is discontinued.

Comment: It's wrong. Вouble check it. In my rails 6 project I use secrets.yml and everything works fine.

Comment: In Rails 6 you may use config/credentials/$environment.yml.enc instead secrets.yml, but secrets.yml will work also.

Comment: so did you manually make `secrets.yml` file inside of project?

Comment: Yep. `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` will become available

Comment: I am trying to working out. Mikhail, Thanks for your help. I will update my one soon.